# Body class trace for Joomla template like WordPress

Tags: wordpress, templates, joomla

How can I trace all the relevant tags of a page in the form of classes to the `<body>` tag? I'm referring to how Wordpress puts the following in a page's body class attribute:

`home page page-id-12766 page-template page-template-page-home-php cufon2-disabled safari theme-*`

This could be extremely helpful in Joomla template development.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether there is any out of the box solutions exists for this.  As the main structure of the site is mainly based on the Menu structure, the below snippet may be useful. This is used in the templates/mytemplate/index.php file.

```
<?php
    $menu = &JSite::getMenu();
    $active = $menu->getActive();
    $pageclass= '' ;
    //$currentpage = '';  //In case if wanted to get the alias of the current page in a later stage.
    if( count($active->tree) > 0 ) {
        foreach ($active->tree as $key => $value) {
            $pageclass .= 'level-'.$key . ' pageid-'.$value. ' page-'.$menu->getItem($value)->alias ;
            //$currentpage = $menu->getItem($value)->alias;
        }
    }
?>
<body class="<?php echo $pageclass; ?>">
```

This will output something like:

```
<body class="level-0 pageid-101 page-home">
```

You may improve this using various values available in the `$active` variable.

Comment: This works brilliantly, I just changed this following line at the end:
`$pageclass .= 'level-'.$key . ' pageid-'.$value. ' page-'.$menu->getItem($value)->alias.' ';`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some information on the [Body Class Function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class)

How Wordpress determines which classes to apply using it is found in [post-template.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0)

The relevant function you're looking for is get_body_class within this template. It essentially runs a series of checks to determine if the current page meets the criteria for given classes. It also relies heavily on Wordpress specific function calls that helps make that determination.